# Can't debug the build with gcc4.9

Tags: debugging, gcc, optimization, gdb, debug-information

I built executable with gcc4.9, with `-Og` and `-g3` options. When I try to debug with gdb-7.10, I can't see variable values, all are . But looks like there is debug information, I can see source files, set breakpoints... Everything is OK besides values. What can be the reason?

Comment: What is your platform? Linux? Windows? Something else? Does it work if you remove `-Og` ?

Comment: I'm running under Linux. No tried without -Og and it didn't work.